# Hololens Methods of Input and Output

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, hololens

I have planned to start building an application for the Hololens in a month from now. So right now, I am just in the preliminary design and feasibility check. (For the record I have built simple applications for the Hololens using Unity and also have used the camera for some image recognition)

My main concern is methods of inputing data to my application. In a normal application you have GUI widgets such as spinners or sliders, if you want to enter a numberic number.

How can I input numeric values to a Hololens application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you've made a few applications for HoloLens before I'm guessing you know about the [MixedRealityToolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity) That Microsoft offers. If you don't know about it yet, and want to use it, here is a [quick guide](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/master/GettingStarted.md)  for how to set it up (which can also be found on the MixedRealityToolkit Github).   In this toolkit there are a lot of tools that can help you with building the interactions for the HoloLens.

In this toolkit there are also a few examples on how to go about making sliders and other sorts of input.

If you look under [Examples/UX](https://github.com/Microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/tree/master/Assets/HoloToolkit-Examples/UX) you'll see a few scenes/prefabs/scripts that give an example on how you could go about making such GUI widgets for hololens

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful comment. I will take a look and come back