# Entering data to a Hololens Application

Tags: user-input, toolkit, hololens

I am in the design process of a Hololens Application. This application needs to get plenty of data (numerical, string, etc), and I am wondering how can I do this.

For numerical or event input I got [suggested to use the Mixed Reality Toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50460917/hololens-methods-of-input-and-output). I have investigated this, made some simple samples and seems quite good.

But for example, say I want an application in which I can enter a user's name, address, job place, school name , etc type of data... how can I enter this to my Hololens Appli?

I see there is a holo keyboard method in the toolkit but it is very cumbersome to type with taps.

Another option would be to have it written on a paper and use letter recognition, but well that is not that simple

Is there any other way to input this type of data to my application?

Comment: Your main options are keyboard and voice, both of which are built in to the MRTK... but mixed reality isn't going to be a good fit for long data entry.  I'd recommend using a keyboard with voice input option, and minimize the amount of data entry users have to do.

Answer (score 2):

## Option 1:

Use Microsoft HoloLens App on Windows 10:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/microsoft-hololens/9nblggh4qwnx

This will allow you to remotely type live or when you are done click send.
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YX9U4.png),[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjDMV.png)
You can connect with it to HoloLens using Bluetooth and type that way.

## Option 2:

Use Microsoft HoloLens Portal in your browser: **[Portal Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuwiI.png)**

1. Login to your portal: 
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/using-the-windows-device-portal
2. Click on **System** tab
3. Click on **Virtual Input**
4. Type in the Input text box and then click **Send**

## Option 3:

Buy **Microsoft XBox Wireless Controller** and **XBox Keyboard** for it.

Wireless Keyboard ChatPad: 
[https://www.amazon.com/Wireless-Keyboard-Microsoft-Controller-Receiver/dp/B071XZNW3H/ref=sr_1_1_sspa?ie=UTF8&qid=1539620724&sr=8-1-spons&keywords=XBox+controller+keyboard&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B071XZNW3H)

Good Luck!